# Can Stack Exchange provide a correction on an article?

Tags: discussion, allowed-questions

I am having a doubt in a proof of an article and I am only have the pdf of that article means How can I post Question in some part of the article?

Can I upload that pdf? If so, how?

And if we rewriting a proof of some theorem stated in a book. Is there any possibility to get corrections and comments from good mathematicians online by posting the complete article through any stackexchange forum?

Comment: short answer: no

Comment: You post contains several unrelated questions, some (maybe all) of them have been discussed here. For question about uploading see [Can I upload a pdf file along with a question/answer?](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/1982/can-i-upload-a-pdf-file-along-with-a-question-answer).

Comment: However, you can still post a link to the pdf file with the article. But you should try to **make post self-contained**. As you can easily check some people include images from [books](http://images.google.com/images?q=books+site:math.stackexchange.com) and [papers](http://images.google.com/images?q=paper+site:math.stackexchange.com) in their posts.
(You can try to export them from the software you use to view the file. Some people simply take screenshot.) See also this discussion:
[On the inclusion of pages-of-text-as-images in questions](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/1805/).

Comment: thank you.......

Comment: Is there any website to do my requirements...

Comment: I am not entirely sure what you mean by *complete article*. Posting a paper was discussed in [Submitting a paper for review](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/4125/submitting-a-paper-for-review). But if you want to post your solution of some exercise from a textbook, this is certainly allowed. See [here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/15014/is-this-site-the-right-one-to-get-a-review-to-a-mathematical-solution),
[here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/4597/best-way-of-asking-check-my-proof-questions) and other questions linked to these two.

Answer (score 10):

Questions about the details of particular proofs in published articles and books are on topic. But they should be as self-contained as possible. Reproduce the relevant part, and give a reference/link to the source for additional context.

(If retyping a few paragraphs sounds like too much work, then you don't really need to ask the question.)